# Add dividing line between flex items with equal space distribution

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list with different items which have auto widths (no fixed width can be given in my case). I use `justify-content: space-between` because my first item has to start at the beginning of the container and my last item at the end.

All of the above works fine, but whenever I try to add a line between these list items, the problems start to emerge. I have no way to determine how many px or % I have to position these lines. Is there any way to 'dynamically' position the lines between the different list-items or not?

**The html we are using is not editable as it is rendered by the CMS we are using.**

This is what I have:

[image: This is what I have]

This is what I try to achieve

[image: Here is what I would like to achieve]

Here is the code I currently have

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Container {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.Flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Flex-item {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.Flex-item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 1px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Flex">
         <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm using this solution on a project I'm working on.

It sets `justify-content: space-between;` on the flex container and `flex: 1 1 auto;` on the children with a left border on all childrens except first.

I modified your example CSS so you can have a look. I wasn't sure if you were going to have background color on the children so I just used line-height to get larger borders.

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Container {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.Flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Flex-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.Flex-item + .Flex-item {
    border-left: solid 1px white;
}

/** Optional for OPs exact layout */

.Flex-item:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

.Flex-item:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Flex">
        <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
        <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
        <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
        <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
        <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No modification to HTML.

Comment: One difference I see between this and the OP's desired layout is that the first and last items are not flush with the left and right edges.

Comment: Sure. I can't remember if I was aware of this when I made the snipped but it can be fixed by adding `Flex-item:first-child { text-align: left; }` `Flex-item:last-child { text-align: right; }` if you need it. I have edited the original solution also.

Comment: First and last item now have bigger spacing than the other items. Is it possible to make it consistent ?

Comment: What is the point of adding Flex-item twice, like `.Flex-item + .Flex-item` ?

Comment: It's the CSS selector for adjacent sibling. So the element with the class `Flex-item` next to an element with class `Flex-item` gets a border to the left. In this case it's to "skip" the first element having a left border.

It's so you don't have to write `.Flex-item:first-child { border-left: 0; }`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `:after` use a stylistic, ARIA representational LIs

```
<li class="separator" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></li>
```

like:

```css
.Container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}

.Flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none; padding: 20px 0; margin:0;
}

.Flex-item {
  background: red;
}

.separator {
  background: white; width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="Flex">
    <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
    <li class="separator" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></li>
    <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
    <li class="separator" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></li>
    <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
    <li class="separator" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></li>
    <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
    <li class="separator" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"></li>
    <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S: yes, I tried using `display: list-item` initially on the `:after` pseudo but naah.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response. Unfortunately we aren't able to modify the html as the html is rendered by our CMS :/. So adding a separator is not an option

Comment: Also, assistive technology will now see a list of 10 items.

Answer (score 7):

You can *make it work* by using a *nested* `flexbox`es - I understand you can't change the markup, but at least you have to wrap the contents of the `li` into a `span` like I have here:

1. Make `.flex-item` also a `flexbox` with the text in a `span` (this would have the red background now) and the *separator* as an `:after` element
2. Apply `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to 1 and `flex-basis` to `auto` for the `Flex-item`.
3. The `flex: 0` to the last `Flex-item` and `margin-auto` to the `:after` also contributes to the effect.

A demo may explain it better - see below:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.Flex-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.Flex-item span {
  background: red;
}
.Flex-item:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}
.Flex-item:last-child {
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="Flex">
    <li class="Flex-item">
      <span>Lorem</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Flex-item">
      <span>consectetur</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Flex-item">
      <span>vestibulum</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Flex-item">
      <span>nec</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Flex-item">
      <span>condimentum</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer may not be valid, as it changes the mark-up, which is not an option, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to accomplish this with flexbox is to wrap the text in a new element, as @Kukkuz has done in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41632218/3597276).

Without that extra wrapper, you can still get the equal spaced dividers, but the red background isn't confined to the length of the text.

Below is an example with:

- No changes to the HTML.
- No need for pseudo elements.
- No need for absolute positioning.

If a background color for the text isn't necessary, then remove it and this should be all you need.

```css
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.Flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: red;
}
.Flex-item {
  text-align: center;
}
.Flex-item:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.Flex-item:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.Flex-item + .Flex-item {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.Container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="Flex">
    <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
    <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
    <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
    <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
    <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you can add a `span` around the text, which will allow you to limit the red background to the length of the text, then you're all set:

```css
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.Flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.Flex-item span {
    background-color: red;
}
.Flex-item:first-child span {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.Flex-item:last-child span {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.Flex-item + .Flex-item {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.Container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="Flex">
    <li class="Flex-item"><span>Lorem</span></li>
    <li class="Flex-item"><span>consectetur</span></li>
    <li class="Flex-item"><span>vestibulum</span></li>
    <li class="Flex-item"><span>nec</span></li>
    <li class="Flex-item"><span>condimentum</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution:

```css
.Container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.Flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Flex-item {
  /* here's part of the trick (content-box) */
  background: red content-box;
}

/* here's part of the trick */
.Flex-item + .Flex-item {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Flex">
         <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you imbricate `flex`, you might get something **close** to what you try to do without any extra markup.

It involves pseudos, `order` & css3 selectors(fine aside `flex`).

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BpzYWP

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.Flex, .Flex-item {
  display:flex;
  padding:0.5em 0;
  margin:0;
}
.Flex-item  {
  flex:1;/*spray them evenly*/
  
}
.Flex-item:before,
.Flex-item:after {/* add pseudos to fill extra space */
  content:'';
  flex:1;/* thats where it takes room not use by the text */
  margin:-1em 0;/* grow them taller */
  border-right:solid 1px white;
}
.Flex-item:first-child:before
{
  order:2;/* put both pseudo after text*/ 
  flex:.5;/* shrink that one can be .75 to .25 */
  border:none; /* remove the border useless for the show */
}

.Flex-item:last-child:after {
  order:-1;/* put both pseudos before text */
  flex:0.5;/* shrink that one can be .75 to .25 */
}
.Flex-item:first-child + .Flex-item:before ,
.Flex-item:nth-last-child(1):after{
  border:none; /* remove the border useless for the show */
}
body, :after, :before {
  background:tomato;/* pseudo will hide li background */
}
li {
  background:turquoise;
}

/* give some space around the text */
.Flex-item:first-child {
  padding-left:1em;
}
.Flex-item:last-child {
  padding-right:1em;
}
.Flex-item:before {
  border:none;/* we do not need those after all */
  margin-right:1em;
}
.Flex-item:after {
  margin-left:1em;
}
.Flex-item:first-child:before {
  margin:-1em 0;
}.Flex-item:last-child:after {
  margin:-1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Flex">
         <li class="Flex-item">Lorem</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">consectetur</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">vestibulum</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">nec</li>
         <li class="Flex-item">condimentum</li>      
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Container {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: blue;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Flex {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    float: left;
}

.Flex-item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
.Flex-item:last-child{border-right:none;}

.Flex-item >div{
  margin:0 5px;
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Flex">
         <li class="Flex-item"><div>
         Lorem
         </div></li>
         <li class="Flex-item"><div>
         consectetur
         </div></li>
         <li class="Flex-item"><div>
         vestibulum
         </div></li>
         <li class="Flex-item"><div>
         nec
         </div></li>
         <li class="Flex-item"><div>
         condimentum
         </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```